# Interpolated Line shows in EPSG:4326 but disappears in others

Tags: qgis, line, rivers

I'm trying to stylize rivers but it's impossible since Interpolated Line ("tapered line") shows only in EPSG:4326 but disappears in EPSG:3857 and EPSG:25835. I have no idea why is that.

Comment: This is either a projection problem (like attributing a different projection rather than reprojecting) or  a symbolisation problem if you use "map unit"  setting as 3857 and 25835 use meter as unit while 4326 use degree

Comment: It was a projection problem - thank you.